# The Python 3.3 equivalent of 'execfile'

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyword, execfile

I need to find out how to open my *.py* files after writing them in Notepad++. I find the interface more useful than the Python window.

In a tutorial I was following along with the guy uses

```
execfile(pathway)
```

but execfile does not work in 3.3.

Is there an equivalent statement in 3.x?

Comment: I can never find answers on here, yet everyone else finds them so easily, thanks. The ones I was looking at were all imports and python filname.py

Comment: exec(open('Users\Deaven and Teigan\Document\Python Projects\Stock.py'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#21>", line 1, in <module>
    exec(open('Users\Deaven and Teigan\Document\Python Projects\Stock.py'))
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Users\\Deaven and Teigan\\Document\\Python Projects\\Stock.py'

Comment: In windows try with the drive letter, like `r"C:\Users\path\to\the\file"` or with a starting backslash. If you are generating the file path with `os.path`, use `os.path.abspath`.